# Join array without removing whitespace

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a little question about joining arrays. I have an array of letters, something like that:

```
let array = ['a','b','','c']
```

I wan't to join elements in array to have output like that:

```
let array = ['ab','c']
```

Can you help me? I was searching but everything i found was about removing whitespaces from arrays or string :(

Comment: What will happen for this case `['a','b','','c','d']`

Comment: So, you want to concatenate adjacent elements, unless that element is an empty string, which would signify a break between elements?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Exactly which pattern you will like to have? What happens for cases like mentioned above.

Comment: If array is ['a','b',' ','c','d',' ','e','f'] I wan't to get ['ab','cd','ef']

Comment: Anyway guys I really gave you example what I want but you gave me for that -4 reputation... No words for your behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [`String#Split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to achieve what you want.

Here, I used a `space` as the delimiter, but you can use anything that you don't use in your array.

```js
let array = ['a','b','','c'];

let result = array.map(e => e.length ? e : ' ').join('').split(' ');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What if the original array has a space as one of the elements? OP hasn't provided enough details.

Comment: But this doesnt work as expected for array with an array like `['a','b','','c', 'd', 'e'];`

Comment: @CristianS. Yes it does.

Comment: @Zenoo it returns ["ab", "cde"] , and I assume hes trying to join 2 elements only.. Well TBH the OP is not clear enough. (not my downvote!)

Comment: @CristianS. For me, as I understood it, OP has a Char Array, that he wants to converts to a word Array. I could be wrong, I'll just leave my answer here in case I'm right.

Comment: If array is ['a','b',' ','c','d',' ','e','f'] I wan't to get ['ab','cd','ef']

Comment: @Gnex That's exactly what my answer does ^^

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines:

```js
let array = ['a', 'b', '', 'c'];

let res = array.reduce((res, s) => {
    if (s.length) {
        res[res.length - 1] += s;
    } else {
        res.push('');
    }
    return res;
}, ['']);

console.log(res);
```

It does make the assumption that there will be at least one string in the array, that the last element won't be an empty string and that there won't be two adjacent empty strings. Adjust as necessary if those are concerns.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce()` method to create new array and one variable to increment on empty string.

```js
let array = ['a', 'b', '', 'c', 'd', 'e', '', '', '', 'f', '', 'g'];

let i = 0;
let result = array.reduce((r, e, j, arr) => {
  r[i] = (r[i] || '') + e;
  if (!e && arr[j - 1]) i++
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```